# deploying java webapp on Gae using maven plugin

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a web app on GAE using maven plugin, when I run the app engine maven starts downloading a ton of repositories and its never finishing is it normal?

Comment: please post your maven file

Comment: Hi Michael, I decided to change from maven to netbeans GAE plugin and its working fine. thanks for replying : )        .